# For loop ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop across a list of exchange rate dataframes, to calculate the cross rate and convert them into a different base currency. The code I'm currently running is:

```
forex_dataframes = [aud_df, eur_df, gbp_df, nzd_df, cny_df, jpy_df]

for i in forex_dataframes:
    if (i == nzd_df).all():
        continue
    else:
        i = nzd_df / i
```

The calculation should be `nzd_df / *currency_df*` for every dataframe except nzd_df, as this is already correct.

When I run this code though I'm getting

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

I'm not sure why this is the case as when I print it individually (e.g. `(nzd_df == nzd_df).all()`) I get a single boolean value back.

Note the `forex_dataframes` list needs to be in this particular order, but if there is another way of skipping the nzd_df item I'm happy to go with that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "The calculation should be *currency_df* / nzd_df for every dataframe except nzd_df, as this is already correct." Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. If you need to treat that item differently from the rest of the list, it should be held separately from the list in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [show the complete traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: I think you can not use .all like that, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: It would be better if you show us what your dfs look like